# Reference to undefined setting in plugin of multi-project sbt

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, multi-project

I have the following project definition (simplified):

```
object B extends Build {
  lazy val root = (project in file("."))
    .aggregate(commons, processor)

  lazy val commons = (project in file("commons"))

  lazy val processor = (project in file("processor"))
    .enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin, BuildTag)
}
```

and the `BuildTag` plugin (also simplified to the issue at hand):

```
object BuildTag extends AutoPlugin {

  override def requires = BuildInfoPlugin

  override lazy val buildSettings = Seq(
    packageOptions in (Compile, packageBin) += {
      Package.ManifestAttributes(("buildinfo.package", (buildInfoPackage in Compile).value))
    }
  )
}
```

when I load the project, I get an error like:

```
Reference to undefined setting: 

  {.}/compile:buildInfoPackage from {.}/compile:packageBin::packageOptions
```

It looks like sbt is trying to reference the setting outside of the scope where the plugin is using it. Why might that be and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was not the multi-module nature, because it is reproducible also in a single-module project.

However instead of

```
override lazy val buildSettings = ...
```

you need to use `projectSettings` to make the `buildInfoPackage` task usable.